# Add-Content, Start-Transcript, and Remove-Item not working at Startup via a Task

Tags: windows, powershell

I thought I had this issue entirely solved but not. Dug into it a bit more and learned a few more things.

**Goal**

- Create Log File on startup to a file share using a UNC path. Uses `Add-Content`.
- Use `Start-Transcript` to create a local log of the PS Script that is running.
- Remove files once complete using `Remove-Item`.

**Issue** - Only some of the time. Some times everything works perfectly

- Logs are not being created, and files are not being removed
- If one of these things are not working, then they are all failing. I have no seen in my testing where only one of these actions is complete.
- I do not have any error to show or help me identify the issue. The script is being run by a task via Task Scheduler using the SYSTEM Account

Unsure where to turn without an error or something.

**This is how Task is Created**

```
$Task_Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PowerShell.exe' -Argument '-File C:\Script.ps1'
$Task_Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId SYSTEM -RunLevel Highest
$Task_Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Hidden
$Task_Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup

Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName "This is Task" `
    -Action $Task_Action `
    -Principal $Task_Principal `
    -Trigger $Task_Trigger `
    -Settings $Task_Settings `
    -Force
```

**This is how transcript is created**

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\Logs\Transcript.txt"
```

**This is how log via UNC Path is added**

```
Function WriteTo-LogFile($Text_For_Log) {
    $Log_DateTime = (Get-Date).ToFileTimeUtc()
    Add-Content -Path $Log_File -Value ($Log_DateTime + ",$Text_For_Log")
}

WriteTo-LogFile ("Adding Stuff to Log.")
```

Comment: Well I can't tell you the specifics in detail but I suspect that your issue stems from the system account not having rights to the share.

Comment: That wouldn't explain not being able write to the C Drive with `Start-Transcript`or being able to use `Remove-Item` both are local to the machine. What could be different between SYSTEM Accounts on the machines?

Comment: @Backin Without seeing your script, we don't know the order of your calls and which one may be the actual problem.